# Difference between call and prototype.call

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, is there a reason to prefer

this:

```
[].forEach.call(...)
```

over this:

```
[].prototype.forEach.call(...)
```

.. ?

Comment: Shorter of a chain to get through to the method. They both reference the same function. If you were using `Array` (instead of `[]`), you'd have to use `Array.prototype.forEach`

Comment: @Ian You missed something : there's no `[].prototype`.

Comment: @dystroy Wow, totally blanked on that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is shorter, thus easier to read and potentially preventing horizontal scrolling.

The second one is buggy as there's no `[].prototype` (did you mean `[].constructor.prototype` ?)

The third one would be

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(...)
```

This one is more direct and theoretically faster, as what you get with the first one is indirectly the property that is, in fact, attached to the prototype.

Answer (score 0):

The second example won't work, so if we correct it to...

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call
```

Now if we compare this against `[].forEach.call`, the difference is that with the prototype-version, you're not creating a throwaway array object.

Whether or not this makes any difference in practice depends on your specific case. If you're doing this repeatedly hundreds or maybe thousands of times, creating these throwaway array objects can cause higher memory usage and slower GC sweeps in comparison to calling the function directly via the prototype.